# Sending a lot of data in batches

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv, batch-processing

I use a jQuery CSV importer to import CSV files. After I've processed the import, I have an object that contains an object for each row that looks like this:

```
{
    {
        'name':'foo',
        'surname':'bar',
        'tel':'0123456789'
    },
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Because the csv file may have 10 rows or a 1000 rows, I want to now send this data in batches to the server. I already have a function that splits the object into pieces and then posts it.

```
/**
 * @method sendChunks Sends data in chunks to the micro-service
 * @param object {object} Data that needs to be sliced up and sent
 * @param size {int} Size of chunks
 * @param endpoint {string} Where the data needs to be sent
 * @param callback {function} Callback function when all pieces are sent.
 */
function sendChunks(object,size,endpoint,callback) {
    var counter = 0,
        total = 0,
        sendObj = {
            'source':config.source,
            'country_code':config.country_code,
            'language_code':config.language_code,
            'batch_data': [],
        };
    objectLength = object.count();
    $.each(object, function (i, obj) {
        total++;
        if(counter < size && total != objectLength) {
            counter++;
            sendObj.batch_data.push(obj);
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'some_url',
                type: 'post',
                data: sendObj,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(total == objectLength) {
                        setNotification('Import completed','Contact was successfully imported.','panel-success panel');
                    }
                }
            });
            if(total == objectLength) {
                if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback();
                } else {
                    console.log('failed to call function');
                }
            }
            counter = 1;
            sendObj.batch_data = []
        }
    })
},
```

Problem is, the ajax requests are firing all at once. I want them to fire one after the other. How can I make it send the next batch only after the previous batch has finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `async: false` parameter to your ajax call :

```
         $.ajax({
            url: 'some_url',
            type: 'post',
            async: false, // <== one by one
            ...
```

> **async** (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Comment: I did see async but what worries me is that it may temporarily lock the browser. I want to know if there is a way to do this while avoiding a browser lock.

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/, it's a little bit more complicated but it doesn't lock the browser.